# Always keep text view in center of Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

i want to create a custom view extending ConstraintLayout in which i am having a textview.I want text view to be always in center of ConstraintLayout irrespect of its width .Here is the code

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context,attributeSet: AttributeSet):ConstraintLayout(context,attributeSet) {
var textView:AppCompatTextView
 var constraintView:ConstraintLayout


init {
    val height: String =
        attributeSet.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_height")
    val width: String =
        attributeSet.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_width")

    background=resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.upsell_unselected_text_bg_for_discount_rectangle)
    textView= AppCompatTextView(context)
    constraintView=this
    textView.id=R.id.vtextview
    constraintView.id=R.id.vlinecview
   textView.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black))

    textView.text="B"
    textView.rotation=90F
    textView.textSize=60F
    textView.setSingleLine()
    textView.maxLines=1
    textView.maxEms=7
    textView.ellipsize= TextUtils.TruncateAt.END
    textView.setHorizontallyScrolling(false)
    TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(textView, 30, 180, 1,TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);
    constraintView.addView(textView)
    var layoutParams=ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_SPREAD,ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
    layoutParams.topToTop=R.id.vlinecview
    layoutParams.bottomToBottom=R.id.vlinecview
    layoutParams.startToStart=R.id.vlinecview
    layoutParams.endToEnd=R.id.vlinecview
    textView.layoutParams=layoutParams
    textView.bringToFront()

    }

fun setTextSize(textsize:Float)
{
textView.textSize=textsize
}
 fun setTextColor(tcolor:Int)
 {
     textView.setTextColor(tcolor)
 }
fun setText(str:String)
{
    textView.text=str
}

}
```

But when i use this customView with width 70dp ,the text view does not fit center of CustomView and can anyone please tell me how to size textView according to width of layout

Comment: if view is fixed To make things easy why not just inflate a layout inside your Custom View ?

Comment: Create a linear layout in your constraint layout and center it (sizes of this linear layout would be wrap_content) and add your custom view to it programatically

Comment: @ADM i want the textview to always remain in center and reduce it size according to parent layout